# dlib - face detector error: cannot convert std::vector<dlib::rectangle> to int

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, dlib

my attempt to move a few steps inside dlib came to an abrupt halt while trying to replicate some parts of this code
http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html

This is what I've got so far

```
// video and image capturing
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video.hpp"

//Dlib libraries
#include "dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h"
#include "dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h"
#include "dlib/image_processing.h"
#include "dlib/gui_widgets.h"
#include "dlib/image_io.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace dlib;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
    shape_predictor sp;


    array2d<rgb_pixel> img;

    VideoCapture cap("/home/francesco/Downloads/05-1.avi");

    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file. \n";
        return -1;
    }

    double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); //get the frames per second

    namedWindow("UNLTD", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    //For future: WINDOW_OPENGL instead of WINDOW_AUTOSIZE;

    while(1)
    {
        Mat frame;
        //Mat is basic image container, frame is an object of Mat.


        std::vector<rectangle> dets = detector(img);

        if (!cap.read(frame))
        //read() decodes and capture the next frame, if it fails, break
        {
            cout << "Failed to read the video. \n";
            break;

        }

        imshow("UNLTD", frame);

        if(waitKey(30) == 27) //ESCAPE
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

For now, all I'm expecting the software to do is to play the video without returning errors but unfortunately I'm getting this

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
error: template argument 2 is invalid
error: cannot convert 'std::vector<dlib::rectangle>' to 'int' in initialization
```

referring to the line

```
 std::vector<rectangle> dets = detector(img);
```

which I copied/pasted from the example provided in the official dlib.net website.

Build log:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++11 -I../../../../opt/opencv/include/opencv -I../../../../opt/opencv/include/opencv2 -c /home/francesco/dlib/OpenCV_videoPlayer_v01/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
/home/francesco/dlib/OpenCV_videoPlayer_v01/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/francesco/dlib/OpenCV_videoPlayer_v01/main.cpp:46:30: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     std::vector<rectangle> dets = detector(img);
                          ^
/home/francesco/dlib/OpenCV_videoPlayer_v01/main.cpp:46:30: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/home/francesco/dlib/OpenCV_videoPlayer_v01/main.cpp:46:51: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<dlib::rectangle>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
     std::vector<rectangle> dets = detector(img);
                                               ^
```

The full code is available here
http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html

any idea?

Comment: Orthogonal to your question but you didn't actually initialize your `img` variable before running it through the detector.  Spoiler alert: it's not going to detect anything.

Comment: Please provide the full error message. Your compiler should be telling you a lot more detail about what template parameters are invalid. If this is Visual Studio, look in the output window, not the error list.

Comment: I am aware of that, but shouldn't the code run anyway?

Comment: @DarkFalcon I'm using code::blocks , I added the Build log output to the original post

Comment: What if you switch to `auto dets = detector(img);`, does it work?

Comment: @DanielLangr yes, it does. what is this sorcery?

Comment: Check my answer, even it's just a guess. I have no possibility to try it myself now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that the problem is with the `rectangle` identifier, which, as I look at documentations, is defined both in `cv` and `dlib` namespaces. `using namespace ...` is generally not a good idea for multiple namespaces. Try to remove `using namespace cv` and prefix all identifiers from `cv` namespace accordingly.

Comment: You're welcome. Please, accept this answer to prevent this post to appear among unanswered questions.